# How can I fix Chargebee CSP Errors?

Tags: checkout, content-security-policy, chargebee

Ive got a problem by using Chargebee via Drop-In Script and Api.

I already added the following directives to the header:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE1u2.png)

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0S1h.png)

Do we enter the Directives properly?

Api-key, Domain, Site is set correctly for Chargebee-Instance.

We are using the new Featured Full-Page Checkout. We are already checked it on our Test-Environment, but the Live-Environment and after the migration to PCv.2.0 of Chargebee it does not work.Anybody facing the same Problems? The Checkout-Link coming from our backend works as expected.

We are using NUXT Framework and Vue for the Frontend. Laravel as Backend.

Best Regards

What could the cause of that error. Can it may an error, that the URLs are not whitelisted from Chargebee?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the redacted host to connect-src directive.